# JQVMAP Country Coloring

Tags: colors, country, jqvmap

I am using JQVMAP at [here](http://www.chenetwork.org/_new/mapData/). When I have a country that has members I desire to change that country's color without mousing over it, as the map is displayed.

I am using the following sql to get the countries and the number of their members.  My question is what do I do, once I have a country, to change that countries map color?  All countries will have the same color.

`$result=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(profile3.organizations) total_org, LEFT(countryCODEconversions.Code, 2) FROM profile3, countryCODEconversions WHERE TRIM(MID(countryCODEconversions.Code, 4, 147)) = profile3.country GROUP by profile3.country");
        //if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
            $counter = "";
            while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
            {
                foreach ($line as $value) {
                    $counter += 1;
                    $value = stripslashes($value);
                    if ($counter == 1){$total = nl2br($value);}
                    if ($counter == 2){
                        $counter = 0; 
                        $countryCode = strtolower($value);
        ?>
                gdpOrgData['<?=$countryCode?>']=("<?=$total?>");
        <?`

Comment: Do you want to color these countries on loading the map, or do you want to do it live?

Comment: Upon loading the map.

Answer (score 4):

Normaly, after loading the map you can set the color of countries that need a different color like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap('set', 'colors', {lt: '#8c9622', 
                                                    sv: '#8c9622', 
                                                    yr: '#8c9622'});
});
```

You could use PHP to generate the list in this script. Just make sure to load it after the map is loaded. 
I hope this points you in the correct direction.

Comment: That's beautiful and thank you ... I would like to award you 10,000 points for your answer!